# .NET how to make a build-time decision

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

First to give some context:
I want to build an API (ASP.NET core) and in this API I would like to implement 2 ways of authentication.
One very simple, build in the application itself so that it can be contained to just one container. Second authentication with Identity sever that I would run in a separate container.

I could just place an if statement in the Startup.cs that checks an enviroment variable. But this would mean that all the code for both scenarios is compiled. Even tough this would not be the end of the world. I would like to do it proper and was wondering how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: Please expand on authentication. I think you mean authorization to your actions, but please verify. Are these both cases of creating a jwt token that should be handled in a different way or something totally different (one with cookies the other with tokens?)

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras one would use identity server the other one would serve a page that I would specifically for this scenario, and for example I would not want that page and the api endpoints for that page in the project when identity server would be selected in the build

Comment: @HansKeﬆing that would do it for the startup.cs but this would still include the page and endpoints if I am not mistaken. I would prefer not to have them too

Comment: What is the actual goal? why do you care that both scenarios are compiled? Reading configuration at startup and set the behavior accordingly seem like a perfectly normal and 'proper' thing to do.

Comment: @JonasH I want to build a webapp for myself and want to integrate it with a central authentication system, but since I think it might be useful for other people but they might not want to setup a different container just for authentication. So I would like to create a second image where there is a barebones authentication/authorization system, just username password.

Comment: @lieven121 Sure, but why does it need to be compile-time? why not just have it as a configuration? I know several products that default to some built in method for various services, but has the option to change configuration to use a third party service for better performance/scalability/features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a preprocessor directive. It looks something like this

```
#ifdef USE_INTERAL_IDENTITY_SERVER
   // Setup internal identity-server
#else
   // Setup for external identity provider
#endif
```

You can then create four configurations in your csproj file - two for debug and two for release. You define the preprocessor constant (or not) in a configuration like so

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_IternalIP|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>USE_INTERAL_IDENTITY_SERVER</DefineConstants>
...
  </PropertyGroup>
```